# iphone safari iframe inherit viewport meta tag

Tags: iphone, mobile, safari, meta-tags

I am building a web app and have the following meta tags in the header. The problem is when opening an iframe (for rss content sources) the iframe seems to inherit these settings so there is no way to scale/scroll inside the iframe.

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
```

Apart from opening the link in a new page is anyone aware of a solution that would work in the same page?

Comment: I've also experienced this when embedding a YouTube player with their iframe api...